# Trying to combine two onEdit scripts (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Was wondering if anyone can help.

I currently have two scripts that I need to combine (to work on single spreadsheet) the first moves a completed row to new sheet;

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Current
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // test column with yes/no is col V
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Current" && r.getColumn() == 24 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Complete");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

and the second auto-sorts rows based on a value;

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 14;
  var tableRange = "A3:X150"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

In an attempt to combine the two I've come up with this....

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
  myFunction2();
}

function myFunction1(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Current
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // test column with yes/no is col V
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Current" && r.getColumn() == 24 && r.getValue() == "Yes") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Complete");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}

function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 14;
  var tableRange = "A3:X150"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
}
```

The first script works but the second doesn't (won't auto-sort), can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Link to spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ghFq3MVwiLL_ft6xdEc8Kk32DNvL-Pb0Rv1avF9oPt4/edit?usp=sharing);

Comment: Should I assume the extra "}" is not in your actual code?
That is to say, that right now, Function2 is inside Function1.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, `myFunction2()` is inside `myFunction1()`. If you move it to it's own outside function, `onEdit()` should be able to call it. If you have variables that need to be used in `myFunction1()` and then called again in `myFunction2()`, you are right in keeping `myFunction2()` as a nested function.

You will, however, need to have `myFunction1()` call `myFunction2()` at the very end before the last bracket. In this case, you would then only need `onEdit()` to call `myFunction1()` and the whole code will run (seeing as `onEdit()` calls `myFunction1()`; `myFunction1()` calls `myFunction2()`

Therefore, your two options should look like this:

Unnested:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
  myFunction2();
}

function myFunction1(event) {
  // start of code
  if(condition == met) {
    //operation to follow
  } //closes if statement operations
} //***this is your misplaced bracket***

function myFunction2() {
  //start of code
  if(condition == met){   
    //operation to follow
  }
}
```

Nested:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
}

function myFunction1(event) {
  // start of code
  if(condition == met) {
    //operation to follow
  } //closes if statement operations; no close to myFunction1()

  function myFunction2() {
    //start of code
    if(condition == met){   
      //operation to follow
    } //closes if statement operation
  } //closes myFunction2()
  myFunction2(); //calls myFunction2() so that it will run after myFunction1() code
} // closes myFunction1()
```

In short, you've set and defined everything for myFunction2() but have not officially told the code to perform those operations.

Comment: Worked a treat, and was a well-explained solution many thanks for taking the time to answer this question and hope it helps other users in future....

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer so that others can find it later.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
function onEdit(event) {
  myFunction1(event);
  myFunction2(event); // you forgotten to pass the event here
}
.
.
.
function myFunction2(event) {  // you forgotten to pass the event here
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanation are better (reference: [answer]). The problem with this answer is that there isn't any description.